# Why is it only writing last input to txt?

Tags: python

Output:

[image]

Sorry, this was being awfully awkward when I trying to paste my Python code into the code box on this forum post.

Code:

```
# update three quotes to a file

file_name = "my_quote.txt"
# create a file called my_quote.txt
new_file = open(file_name, 'w')
new_file.close()

def update_file(file_name, quote):
    # First open the file
    new_file = open(file_name, 'w')
    new_file.write("This is an update\n")
    new_file.write(quote)
    new_file.write("\n\n")

    # now close the file
    new_file.close()

for index in range(3):
    quote = input("Enter your favorite quote: ")
    update_file(file_name, quote)

# Now print the contents to the screen
new_file = open(file_name, 'r')
 print(new_file.read())

# And finally close the file
new_file.close(
```

Comment: please add the code to the question

Comment: Because you're reopening the file in "w" mode each time you write to it, thereby erasing whatever is in the file. Try "a" mode instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be using append instead of write. When you use write, it creates a new file regardless of what was there before. Try `new_file = open(file_name, 'a')`

Answer (score 0):

> Why is it only writing last input to txt?

Everytime you do `open(file_name, 'w')` it clears the contents of the file and begins to write from the start of the file.

If you would like to append new content to that file do

```
open(file_name, 'a')
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you should use `a` instead of `w` to append to file:

```
new_file = open(file_name, 'a')
```

And [read the docs](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files) before asking of course ;)